# Google Form-side form trigger not firing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

This is a trigger and script coded directly into the form rather than on the spreadsheet that gets the form, I'm not sure if that is why this isn't working or not.

The trigger is set:

```
Owned by: Me
Last Run: null
Deployment: Head
Event: From Form-On form submit
Function: sendEmailFromSheet
```

Things I've tried: having the person who originally owned the form create a trigger yesterday, me create one today.

Filling out the form DOES result in the answers on the result spreadsheet, but it doesn't fire this onSubmitForm trigger, and I have no idea why. Again, it isn't that the function is failing but that it isn't firing at all.

Comment: Can you move the function out of the form code?

Answer (score 1):

Given that the function label is 'sendEmailFromSheet' then I suspect that its waiting for the sheet to receive data. But because the function is in the form it will never run because your trigger references the form and not the sheet.

If you can show us the code behind it then we might could tell you better. But without knowing that part then I think that is the mostly reason.

Comment: the Sheet part is actually a static list of email addresses. it works just fine when triggered from the code editor, the form trigger is just NOT firing (it's not my script, I always do sheets side form code not form side form code, so I haven't seen this problem before).

Comment: Well, then I guess the only answer is to submit it as an issue.